# Software that acts like a photocopy transparency film for your monitor screen?

Tags: windows-10, display

Are there any software that can acts like a transparency film over computer monitor screen for Windows?

Something like ScreenMark but except where I can save the drawings as a files for future usage.

This is what my screen displays, as you can see, the Anki edit screen has many boxes, without any visual aid, it is laborious to find the correct boxes.

[image: Screenshot]

So I draw some lines with whiteboard marker on my monitor, so this is what I actually see.

[image: Edited screenshot]

Obviously, this is not the best solution. I'm looking for a free solution for Windows 10.

Comment: Good question! Your Anki model is one of the most detailed I have ever seen :-)

Comment: Ahaha, Nicolas, nice to see you here!

Comment: You need it to be overlaid *and* able to see it while you work on other things? Would you need to work within the grid it's over?

Comment: Yes, I just want an overlay, and be able to work as usual. Multiple monitor support would be nice too.

Comment: Press **Prt Scr** on your keyboard.  Open **Paint**, click in the main area. Then press **Ctrl V** for paste.  There it is and paint has drawing tools to draw line on it and text on it.  It is all built-in to windows no need to install anything.  Yes you can save in several formats.  I don't have multi-monitors so I can't test that part.